# How do I get this traffic Light sequence to work with the click of the button???

Tags: javascript, html

So, I can get it to go from red to amber, but I am stuck on how to further get it to change to green, back to amber and then red again. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Also, I have created this on dreamwaver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>  

   <h1>Traffic Lights </h1>  

  <img id="light" img src="../../red.jpg"> 

  <button type="button" onClick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>


   <script>

    function changeLights(){

   document.getElementById('light').setAttribute("src","../../amber.jpg")

   document.getElementById('light').setAttribute("src","../../green.jpg")

   document.getElementById('light').setAttribute("src","../../amber.jpg")

   //document.getElementById('light').setAttribute("src","../../red.jpg")


   }

  </script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you expect the change between the 3 (or 4) `setAttribute()` happen so fast that you cannot even notice when running the script? Did you try to debug the function using the dev tools of your browser (hit F12) and see what going on step by step?

Comment: Do you want to change the color at each click or automagically ?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to put the image names into an array and the cycle through the array using a counter. That counter can increase or decrease the count depending on which "end" of the array we've last hit.

Also, don't use inline HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`, etc.) as they create "spaghetti code", they cause global wrapper functions that alter the `this` binding and they don't follow the **[W3C Event Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)** standard. Instead wire elements them up to event handlers via code using **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

```js
// Get references to DOM elements:
var img = document.getElementById('light');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

// Hook click of button up to event handling function
btn.addEventListener("click", changeLights);

// Put image names into an array:
var imgs = ["green.jpg" , "amber.jpg", "red.jpg"];

// Establish counter variable and directional variable
var count = 0;
var additive = 1;

function changeLights(){
  
  // Set image by getting element from array based on current counter value
  img.setAttribute("src","../../" + imgs[count]);
  
  // Verification of action
  console.clear();
  console.log(img);

  // When we hit the edges, reverse direction,
  if(count === 2) {
    additive = -1;  // Go backward
  } else if(count === 0) {
    additive = 1;   // Go forward
  }
  
  // Adjust the count accordingly
  count+= additive;
}
```

```html
<h1>Traffic Lights </h1>  
<img id="light" img src="../../red.jpg"> 
<button type="button" id='btn'>Change Lights</button>
```